# How to load AJAX response to VEX dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the VEX modal dialog for my site. I have elements that I need to load dynamically from an AJAX request to my VEX DIALOG. On submit, I need show a VEX ALERT depending on the response of my AJAX. Can someone show me how I can structure this?

Comment: are you talking about this vex? http://github.hubspot.com/vex/

Comment: Yes. That VEX dialog!

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far and specifically where you are getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need but I hope it helps.

```
vex.dialog.confirm({
       message : 'TITLE',
       callback: function(value){
              if(value){
                   $.ajax({
                        statusCode : { 404: function(){alert('Not Found');} },
                        url: '<your_script_here>'
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(res){
                            var response = res.trim();
                            if(response ==='RESPONSE_1'){
                                vex.dialog.alert('RESPONSE 1 '); 
                            }
                            else (response==='RESPONSE_2'){
                                vex.dialog.alert('RESPONSE 2');
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
              }
       }
   }); // END VEX CONFIRM
```

*** Your AJAX response should return a response like that on the if-else block.